# European forest roads free download GIS

Tags: shapefile, data, line

I'm looking for a free download of a shapefile about forest roads in Europe (I need forest roads of Austria and Slovenia).

Here in Italy you can free download these kind of shp, but actually I can't find a link or a website for downloading austrian and slovenian forest roads, probably because many websites are written in their own languages which I don't understand (fortunately I found highways and urban roads shapefiles, and now I miss only forest roads).

Any suggestion?

Comment: For open data I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using [Overpass turbo](https://overpass-turbo.eu/s/zgs) with [road type track](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:highway#Special_road_types):

> Roads for mostly agricultural or forestry uses.

Comment: Very useful tool! You have to understand the language but potentially it is quite interesting!